# UILabel not wrapping the text inside properly

Tags: ios, swift, layout, uilabel

I am displaying a simple UILabel in the center of the screen with a big string and it is working fine but the problem is, there is some space left on the right side of the label for the text to fit but still it gets wrapped to the second line, why is that and how can I fix it?

Here is the picture of the output

[image]

As you can see there is enough space for the word "for" in the right

my code is below

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad();
        
        let label1 = UILabel();
        view.addSubview(label1);
        label1.text = "This is a label and has very long string in it for testing";
        label1.backgroundColor = .blue;
        label1.numberOfLines = 0;
        label1.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false;
        label1.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.rightAnchor, constant: 20).isActive = true;
        label1.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leftAnchor).isActive = true;
        label1.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor).isActive = true;
    }
}
```